# How to switch folders of pop3 mailboxes using PHP IMAP

Tags: php, imap, pop3

I'm pretty sure there's full support for pop3 inboxes in the PHP IMap library, but I'm not able to find folders other than the inbox.  Is it possible to gather other folders using php imap library for pop3 emails?

Here's the function I'm using to test

```
function allFolderMailCount($connection,$server)
{
    $list = imap_getmailboxes($connection, $server, "*");
    if (is_array($list)) 
    {
        foreach ($list as $key => $val) 
        {
            $folderEmails .= $val->name . '  ---- ' . email_folder_count($connection, $val->name);
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
       $folderEmails .= "imap_getmailboxes failed: " . imap_last_error() . "\n";
    }
    return $folderEmails;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

POP3 does not have the notion of "folders". What you want to do is therefore impossible. Switch to the IMAP protocol if you need support for folders.

Comment: Let me get more specific - I created a folder in my Hotmail account called Bob's Folder and can put email there - how does this work?

Comment: And I the emails in that "folder" (or whatever it actually is), don't show up (in the # message count or in the display of all messages) when I connect to the server using the php imap library.

Comment: POP3 does not have the notion of folders. What you see is only the inbox folder since all others are unsupported by the protocol. POP3 is meant to be a delivery mechanism where you download your messages from the server and then save them locally in your client. It's not meant to be an online protocol where you have your messages in the cloud. Almost all modern uses of POP3 is therefore futile since it doesn't handle features you expect from a modern mail server.

Comment: Thanks Emil - that's very helpful - I'm trying to grasp where Hotmail is storing the emails in these non "Folders" - I guess they call them folders for user experince - are they just storing them in a database and creating a guise of a folder?

Comment: I think you mix two different conecpts. How they store the mail is irrelevant. POP3, IMAP and even the web interface are just different views of the same storage. They can use folders if they want since they have at least two protocols supporting them (IMAP and web), but they have to remove features from POP3 which are not supported, in the same way that address books aren't supported over IMAP. Hotmail may very well store mail in folders, a database or with some other solution but that does not matter to you - you should only care about what is visible to over the available protocols.

Comment: I assumed it was up to the mail server whether or not to make IMAP, POP3, or both available.  In gmail I can get to both, but I can't in hotmail - does this mean they only offer pop?  - does this mean I don't have access to the folders I create in hotmail since they only offer POP3 - as far as I know. Sorry about the frequent comments, I'm just trying to make sure I fully understand the concepts.

Comment: Yes, it's up to the server which services they provide. If they don't have IMAP, change to a sane provider. If you really want to stay with Hotmail, check out their Exchange support (which is a mostly secret protocol so you will have a hard time finding a stable client library).

Comment: It's testing I'm doing for an application - with POP, it seems that when a user deletes an email, it's gone forever, but with most IMAP systems, it goes to the trash folder.  Thanks for helping out - looks like i'll need to do a subscription based service for these POP folder providers.